# Action script 3 mute button

Tags: flash, button, action, mute

I have this action script code that is working perfectly but i am try to reverse the process where the movie starts without any sound, and then when you click the button the music will be unmuted.

It seems i can't figure out how to do this. Maybe some one can show me how it is done, i really know nothing about action script 3

```
function setMute(vol){
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0,0);
sTransform.volume = vol; SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}
var Mute:Boolean = false;
mutebutton.addEventListener
(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);
function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event){ if(Mute){ Mute = false; setMute(1);
mutte.gotoAndStop(1); }
else{ Mute = true; 
setMute(0);
mutte.gotoAndStop(2); }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event)` =>

   `function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event = NULL)`

   This allows you to call the function without triggering an Event.
2. Use `toggleMuteBtn();` anywhere you need to mute/unmute. Using it once when the application starts will set your initial state to muted instead of unmuted.

Comment: sorry i tried to understand this but i am sure i am doing something wrong as my button is going insane right now :) `function setMute(vol){
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0,0);
sTransform.volume = vol; SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}
var Mute:Boolean = false;
mutebutton.addEventListener
(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);
function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event = NULL) toggleMuteBtn(); { if(Mute){ Mute = false; setMute(1);
mutte.gotoAndStop(1); }
else{ Mute = true; 
setMute(0);
mutte.gotoAndStop(2); }
}`

Comment: I'd recommend a good Actionscript or general programming tutorial to give you an understanding of why your code there is wrong. Don't put things between the function definition and the opening bracket `{`, because they are tightly paired. Put the new `toggleMuteBtn();` somewhere after the last `}` bracket of that function.

Comment: the thing is that i have been on this all day and the only thing i need is this code to start muted [link](http://synatar.com/demosite/) as you can see there things are the other way around. Loading the page with music is not a good thing.

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment, especially the last sentence.

Comment: `function setMute(vol){
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0,0);
sTransform.volume = vol; SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}
var Mute:Boolean = false;
mutebutton.addEventListener
(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);
function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event = NULL)  { if(Mute){ Mute = false; setMute(1);
mutte.gotoAndStop(1); }
else{ Mute = true; 
setMute(0);
mutte.gotoAndStop(2); }
}toggleMuteBtn();
`
My code is still going crazy, i am so bad at this lol.

Comment: any one else who can help me, i am still stuck.

Comment: I finally figured it out with the help of lunixbochs, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code as it should be working to have movie start with muted sound and then when you click a button the sound will be turned on.

```
var mute:Boolean = false;
var st:SoundTransform;// <- variable is exposed to all functions in this script

mutebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);

function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event = null)
{
    if (mute)
    {
        setMute(1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        setMute(0,2);
    }
    // toggle the mute Boolean
    mute = !mute;
}

function setMute(vol:Number, frm:Number):void
{
    st = new SoundTransform(0,0);
    st.volume = vol;
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = st;
    mutte.gotoAndStop(frm);
}
toggleMuteBtn();
```

`